# Issue with rowset of boost tuples with SOCI c++ database access library

Tags: c++, orm, soci

I have a compilation error when using rowset of tuples with the latest soci and boost libraries.

I found an example on the net but it does not compile with the version of SOCI that I use and which is the latest.

The portion which is causing issue is this one:

```
typedef std::vector<boost::tuple<double, double> > V;

soci::rowset<boost::tuple<double, double> > rows
        = sql.prepare << "select x(location),y(location) from cities";
```

Here is the complete code that I got from an example on the net:

```
#include <soci.h>
#include <soci-postgresql.h>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        soci::session sql(soci::postgresql, "dbname=ggl user=ggl password=ggl");

    int count;
    sql << "select count(*) from cities", soci::into(count);
    std::cout << "# Capitals: " << count << std::endl;

    typedef std::vector<boost::tuple<double, double> > V;

    soci::rowset<boost::tuple<double, double> > rows
        = sql.prepare << "select x(location),y(location) from cities";
    V vec;
    std::copy(rows.begin(), rows.end(), std::back_inserter(vec));

    for (V::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->get<0>() << " " << it->get<1>() << std::endl;
    }
}
catch (std::exception const &e)
{
    std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << '\n';
}
return 0;
```

}

It fails on the following line:

```
   soci::rowset<boost::tuple<double, double> > rows
            = sql.prepare << "select x(location),y(location) from cities";
```

And here is the error which I don quite understand:

```
   g++  -c  "/home/ubuntu/dev/testSoci/test.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall  -o ./Debug/test.o -I./include -I/home/ubuntu/dev/tools/QxOrm/include -I/usr/share/qt4/include -I/home/ubuntu/dev/tools/boost_1_48_0  -I. -I. -I/home/ubuntu/dev/tools/soci-3.1.0/core -I/home/ubuntu/dev/tools/soci-3.1.0/backends/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/home/ubuntu/dev/tools/boost_1_48_0/boost 
In file included from /home/ubuntu/dev/tools/soci-3.1.0/core/into-type.h:13,
                 from /home/ubuntu/dev/tools/soci-3.1.0/core/blob-exchange.h:12,
                 from /home/ubuntu/dev/tools/soci-3.1.0/core/soci.h:18,
                 from /home/ubuntu/dev/testSoci/test.cpp:21:
/home/ubuntu/dev/tools/soci-3.1.0/core/exchange-traits.h: In instantiation of ‘soci::details::exchange_traits<boost::tuples::tuple<double, double, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >’:
/home/ubuntu/dev/tools/soci-3.1.0/core/into.h:29:   instantiated from ‘soci::details::into_type_ptr soci::into(T&) [with T = boost::tuples::tuple<double, double, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>]’
/home/ubuntu/dev/tools/soci-3.1.0/core/rowset.h:125:   instantiated from ‘soci::details::rowset_impl<T>::rowset_impl(const soci::details::prepare_temp_type&) [with T = boost::tuples::tuple<double, double, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>]’
/home/ubuntu/dev/tools/soci-3.1.0/core/rowset.h:185:   instantiated from ‘soci::rowset<T>::rowset(const soci::details::prepare_temp_type&) [with T = boost::tuples::tuple<double, double, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>]’
/home/ubuntu/dev/testSoci/test.cpp:51:   instantiated from here
/home/ubuntu/dev/tools/soci-3.1.0/core/exchange-traits.h:34: error: incomplete type ‘soci::details::exchange_traits<boost::tuples::tuple<double, double, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >’ used in nested name specifier
make[1]: *** [Debug/test.o] Error 1
```

Any idea of what could be the cause?

Thanks a lot! Ludovic

---

A solution was

1/ to add parenthesis
       soci::rowset > rows
                = (sql.prepare << "select x(location),y(location) from cities");

2/ to do what is proposed as answer: 
   #include  or the #define

Comment: Did you have a look at the file that generates the error? It seems to me like you have to implement the traits for your own types yourself.

Comment: @PlasmaHH You mean for this type: typedef std::vector<boost::tuple<double, double> > V; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding this header?

```
#include <boost-tuple.h>
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
#define SOCI_USE_BOOST
```

before including soci.h

Comment: Thanks, I did that + added some parenthesis (see my modified question) and it worked.